# Close all viewports (split screens) in Vim at once

Tags: vim, vi

When I use Vim I tend to split my screen in various ways, but when I want to close the editor I have to close each split separately.  Is there a way to close all the splits at one regardless of how many splits I have open?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use `:qa` for "quit all".

If you have unsaved buffers you'll have to add a bang: `:qa!`.

Comment: anyway to quite all splits but without quitting tabs?

Answer (score 14):

If you want to save all the splits as well type `:wqa`

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, `:qall` is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned that `:qa` is what you want.

Because I (used to)<sup>*</sup> want this so often, I have added these to [my `.vimrc`](https://github.com/ap/dotvim/blob/master/vimrc):

```
" missing ZZ and ZQ counterparts:
" quick save-buffer and quit-everything
nnoremap ZS :w<CR>
nnoremap ZX :qa<CR>
```

<sub>* I don’t work much with splits any more since I found [the qbuf plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1910).</sub>

Comment: For some reason I never hopped on the 'ZZ' bandwagon, but I threw your mappings in my .vimrc to test drive them (fewer keystrokes after all).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on qbuf, this ended up being pretty interesting.  I noticed it doesn't have the option to put the buffer in a vertical split so I added this line \"v": "vertical sb #" in my copy, and let the maintainer know.